# cant get socket response in different browsers (listeners)

Tags: sockets, express

this is my controller:

```
this.servindexfile=function(req,res){

        res.sendFile(path+'/public/index.html');    

    }; 

        io.on('connection', function(socket){  

            console.log('conectado');

            socket.on("stocksend", function(stockTitle){

                socket.emit("stocksend",stockTitle);
            });
        });
```

this is my client html file:

```
<head> <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>  </head>

app.controller("LineCtrl", function ($scope,$http) {

    var socket = io();

    $scope.fnadd=function(){

      var inputStock = $scope.newstock;

      if (inputStock!=""){
        socket.emit('stocksend',inputStock);//emit new stock
      }
    };

     socket.on("stocksend",function(dataReceived){

        console.log(dataReceived);
      });
```

when i try to view the data received in other browser different than the one who emitted the call this doesn't show anything. what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean you want to broadcast (send to all connected clients/browsers) the `stocksend` message sent by the server?

Comment: yes , exacly but i only receive the data on the browser that i make the input example. i write "example" and on the console it writes "example" b ut in other browser doesnt show anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`socket.emit()` will send a message to *one* client (in your case, the originating client/browser).

If you want to send a message to all connected clients, you should use [`io.emit()`](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#emit):

```
socket.on("stocksend", function(stockTitle) {
  io.emit("stocksend", stockTitle);
});
```

This will also send the message to the client that represents `socket` (the one that sent the `stocksend` message). If you don't want that, but instead want to broadcast a message to all connected clients *except* the one that sent the message, use [`socket.broadcast.emit()`](http://socket.io/docs/#broadcasting-messages):

```
socket.on("stocksend", function(stockTitle) {
  socket.broadcast.emit("stocksend", stockTitle);
});
```

Comment: thank you verymuch! i was very confused because i was sending the call with socket.emit from the client side that its ok but on the server i was using socket.emit insted io.emit